# htmx - conditional hx-confirm message

Tags: htmx

I have a survey form submitted using `hx-post`. There are multiple buttons that can be used to submit the form - Prev, Next, Finish. This all works fine. However, I wish to display a confirmation alert only when the Finish button is used to submit the form.

I have `hx-confirm` configured on the form attribute, which, by default, fires for all buttons. The [docs](https://htmx.org/docs/#inheritance) indicate that this can be overridden using [inheritance](https://htmx.org/docs/#inheritance)., but this doesn't seem to work. I should be able to unset the confirmation dialogue, or even update the message, but it doesn't work for me.

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/htmx-forked-96fnd7?file=/index.html

Anyone else tried this? Or is there another way to trigger the dialogue conditionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine if you include the hx-post within button element instead of the form:

```
<form hx-confirm="Parent confirmation messageddd">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <button hx-post="https://codesandbox.io/" type="submit">
    Save with confirmationx
  </button>
  <div>
  <button hx-post="https://codesandbox.io/" type="submit" hx-confirm="Inherited confirmation message">
    Save with inherited message
  </button>
  <button hx-post="https://codesandbox.io/" type="submit" hx-confirm="unset">
    Save without confirmation
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. You are right, it does work. But I should not need to duplicate the hx-post form action to force the hx-confirm inheritance? If this was a design decision, I'd been interested to understand why.

Comment: @Howie I'm not sure either. You can ask about it on htmx discord. They are very responsive.

Comment: Cheers. I did that after your earlier reply. Will see what replies I get. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only have confirmation on one button, you can simply put the `hx-confirm` on that particular button and have it make its own POST request.

```
<form hx-post="https://codesandbox.io/">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <button type="submit">
    Prev
  </button>
  <button type="submit">
    Next
  </button>
  <button type="submit" hx-confirm="Really?" hx-post="https://codesandbox.io/" >
    Finish
  </button>
</form>
```

There is some duplication but it's at least minimal. It doesn't make much sense to include the attribute on a form element that has multiple triggers yet you want the behaviour on only on them.

If, however, you wanted all the buttons to have a confirmation dialog except one, then it would indeed be ideal to put it on the form element and use the `hx-confirm="unset"` on the element you don't want the dialog on.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't make sense to include the attribute on the main form. This was just to demo/test inheritance. I only need one action to ask for confirmation. Seems that I either need to duplicate the action, or resort to JS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using hx-disinherit?

This will prevent the inheritance of htmx attributes.

You can put hx-disinherit="hx-confirm" on the form

see https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-disinherit/